# Using ExcelDNA and System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, system.data.sqlite, excel-dna

I have no issues using ExcelDNA and I also have no issues using System.Data.SQLite in a standalone exe.
Howover I have not been able to make both work together for creating an Excel Addin dll (using Visual Studio 2012 and [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) to install the SQLite .NET package) to be used to query an SQLite database.
Not sure if any SQLite dependencies are not getting resolved. All I get: "A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException'" occurred in Unknown Module.and giving a VALUE error in the Excel cell.
So was wondering if anyone here would have successfully used both together and if there are some gotchas I don't know.
I am using the [Northwind SQLite database](http://code.google.com/p/northwindextended/downloads/detail?name=Northwind.Sqlite3.sql) for this test.

---

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

- Create a new C# Class Library project
- PM> Install-Package Excel-DNA
- PM> Install-Package System.Data.SQLite.Core
- Put the Northwind.db file (created from the .sql file you point to) in C:\Temp
- Add this code in your project:

  ```
  using System;
  using System.Data;
  using System.Data.SQLite;
  using ExcelDna.Integration;

  namespace UsingSQLite
  {
      public static class MyFunctions
      {
          static SQLiteConnection _connection;
          static SQLiteCommand _productNameCommand;

          private static void EnsureConnection()
          {
              if (_connection == null)
              {
                  _connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Temp\Northwind.db");
                  _connection.Open();

                  _productNameCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", _connection);
                  _productNameCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", DbType.Int32);
              }
          }

          public static object ProductName(int productID)
          {
              try
              {
                  EnsureConnection();
                  _productNameCommand.Parameters["@ProductID"].Value = productID;
                  return _productNameCommand.ExecuteScalar();
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  return ex.ToString();
              }
          }

      }
  }
  ```
- Press F5 to load and run in Excel.
- Try =ProductName(1) in a cell. You should see "Chai" or a detailed exception message.

It works on my machine :-)

Note that you won't be able to pack the SQLite assembly into the .xll file using ExcelDnaPack, since the packing tool does not support mixed assemblies.

I've also added a sample project for this on GitHub: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Samples/tree/master/UsingSQLite